# Фильтрация select

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Допустим, есть у нас 3 `<select>`.
У всех 3-x одинаковое значение:

> Текст1
>
> Текст2
>
> Текст3

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы при выборе любого `<select>`, из других это значение исчезало

Выбрали 2-ом select'e "Текст 3", тогда 1 и 3 селекта значение "Текст 3" исчезал, и так далее.

Comment: Я ничего не понял с того что ты написал

Comment: Три значения мало, значений должно быть больше селектов, иначе они залипнут в определенном состоянии (начальном).

Comment: @eicto, ИЗНАЧАЛЬНО значение пустое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/tZsTC/) подойдет? И учим "великий и могучий" ))

P.S. Кстати, если надо именно значения сравнивать, то тогда [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/tZsTC/1/).

Comment: не думаю что хочется чтобы исчезал  навсегда

Comment: @eicto, Это дело поправимое. Например, [hide-show](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/tZsTC/2/). Только ж надо знать определенные условия, при которых должны появляться срытые элементы.

Comment: @Deonis поподробнее можно, как это реализовать?)

Comment: @Коте, для того, чтоб что-то подробнее можно было рассказать - надо знать что-то подробнее о том, что вы хотите получить на выходе и  какая, вообще, у вас поставлена задача.

Comment: @Deonis, есть массив Текст1,Текст2,Текст3

1)<select>
<option></option>
<option>Текст1</option>
<option>Текст2</option>
<option>Текст3</option>
2)<select>
....
3)<select>
....

если я выберу из 1-го select Текст 2, то твой вариант он удаляет, а как сделать чтобы возвращало обратно, то есть, 
1-ом списке выбрать "пусто", или другое значение, значение возвращалось обратно...  при этом при выборе "пустого" чтобы из других значение "пусто" не исчезало
+ изначально select может быть уже некоторых выбраны..)

Comment: Можно [таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/tZsTC/3/)

Comment: @Deonis огромное спасибо, <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/SJRS9/">Дополнил...</a>

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").change(function(){
  var el = $(this);
  var val = el.val();
  $("select").not(el).find("option[value='"+val+"']").delete();
});
```